# How can SASL/PLAIN credentials be provided when connecting from pipelinedb to kafka?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pipelinedb

We want to ingest data from Kafka through PipelineDB. Our Kafka setup requires SASL/PLAIN authentication. How can I configure the SASL user and password with the `pipelinedb` / `pipeline_kafka` PostgreSQL extension?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to do it like this:

Apply this [patch](https://github.com/gb198871/pipeline_kafka/commit/e48e7f83e8a9744b901874f06ba5648a180526d4) to pipeline_kafka (the related [issue](https://github.com/pipelinedb/pipeline_kafka/issues/75) was closed, but the patch was never merged).

Then add this configuration to the `postgresql.conf`:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pipelinedb,pipeline_kafka'
pipeline_kafka.broker_version = '1.0.0'
pipeline_kafka.consumer_config = 'security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT,sasl.mechanisms=PLAIN,sasl.username=USER,sasl.password=PASSWORD'
```

Probably there's a better answer, but this worked.